# Как присвоить переменную?

Tags: c#, переменные

Вопрос: Как расчитать сколько одна лодка вмещает в себя людей?

Текст задачи:

> Дано N людей,
>
> J людей влазит на лодку,
>
> определить сколько лодок потребуется.

---

Пример:

12 людей,

на одну лодку влазит 5 человек,

ответ 3 лодки.

Comment: "на одну лодку влазит 5 человек" - *"Все, отлазались."* П.Санаев "Похороните меня за плинтусом"

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Igor я не думаю что такую задачу дадут взрослому человеку. Поэтому необходимо отнестись с пониманием с учетом возраста. Зря ты так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Вводим кол-во человек
            int people = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            // Вводим сколько людей помещается в одну лодку
            int in_one_boat = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // Проверяем, если кол-во людей не делится нацело на кол-во людей в одной лодке, то прибавляем 1, ответ выводим на экран
            if (people % in_one_boat != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((people / in_one_boat) + 1);
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(people / in_one_boat);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А нужно то было всего сделать округление в бОльшую сторону. `Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(12f / 5f));`